# Adding a line break inside Word document(doc, docx) using php file write

Tags: php, file

- I have a word document with few lines( .doc or .docx)
- I need to use php read and write to put a line break in a specific line inside the document

is it possible via php?

Comment: [PHPOffice/PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)